# Can not initialize qml property to {}

Tags: qml

`property variant a: {}`
does not seem to work.  `a` ends up being undefined, rather than an empty dictionary.

I'm not very experienced with Javascript ... what is the correct way to initialize a property to hold an *empty* dictionary?

The following qml prints "qrc:/main.qml:13: TypeError: Type error" on the console.  However, if `a` is initialized to, say `{"dummyentry": 42}`, then
the expected results are logged.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true; width: 600; height: 200

    property variant a: {}

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("initial a="+JSON.stringify(a)) // TypeError: Type error
        a["newkey"] = 999  // gets "TypeError: Type error"
        console.log("updated a="+JSON.stringify(a))
    }
}
```

Comment: This behaviour is all spelled out in the docs http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-var.html. The *reasoning* for the behaviour is less clear to me.

Answer (score 5):

You could refer to [Qt documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-var.html#property-value-initialization-semantics):

> The QML syntax defines that curly braces on the right-hand-side of a property value initialization assignment denote a binding assignment. This can be confusing when initializing a var property, as empty curly braces in JavaScript can denote either an expression block or an empty object declaration. If you wish to initialize a var property to an empty object value, you should wrap the curly braces in parentheses.

Therefore, when using the `property var a: {}`, the curly braces were interpreted as an empty expression, whose result is undefined.

With using the `property var a: ({})` syntax you will create an empty JS object. You can add to it both properties and methods, but with just a set of properties, it will work exactly like a dictionary.

You can access object properties in two ways:

```
objectName.propertyName
objectName["propertyName"]
```

Here you can find more information about JS objects: [link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp).

Answer (score 1):

It must be a qml syntax issue.  The work-around is to say

```
 property variant a: ( {} )
```

As noted in the question, it *does* work to say

```
 property variant a { "somekey": value }
```

...without parenthesis.

Does anyone know how qml is interpreting an unadorned '{}', and why it results in `undefined`?

Comment: (Older and wiser self answering)  `propname: { ... }` treats the `{...}` as a javascript function body, so you have to explicitly "return ..." a value from it.  Just falling off the end of the function returns undefined.